# Disable Button for a period of time using React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want that when the user clicks on this button, it will be disable for a period of time and then it will enable automatically

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
const handleDisable = () => {
setDisable(true);
setTimeout(() => {setDisable(false)}, 3000)
}
<button disabled={disable} onClick={handleDisable}>click me</Button>
```

Comment: Nice, it worked, and how I added a counter to show the seconds that are still missing